# 'gnuplot' not working in visual studio

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2012, gnuplot

I was able to use gnuplot quite easily on ubuntu using eclipse, but I am a newbie in windows. I am using gnuplot in visual studio 13 but the program is aborting and data.temp is not able to get created. Here is the function below:

```
void plotgraph(double xvals[], double yvals[], double x1vals[], int NUM_POINTS)
{

    int NUM_COMMANDS = 4;
char * commandsForGnuplot[] = { "set title \"Concatenated Coding+OFDM[QPSK]\"", "set ylabel 'BER'", "set xlabel 'SNR'", "plot '%temp%\\data.temp' with lines" };
//FILE * temp = fopen_s(&temp, "%temp%\\data.temp", "w");
//char *commandsForGnuplot[] = { "set title \"Concatenated Coding+OFDM[QPSK]\"", "set ylabel 'BER'", "set xlabel 'SNR'", "set logscale y", "set nologscale x", "plot 'data.temp' with lines title 'After coding' , \ 'data.temp1' with lines title 'Before coding'" };
// double xvals[NUM_POINTS] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
//double yvals[NUM_POINTS] = {5.0 ,3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0};
FILE *pipe;
FILE *temp = NULL;
fopen_s(&temp, "%temp%\\data.temp", "w+");
if (temp == NULL) { 
    printf("Error\n");
}
//FILE * temp1 = fopen_s(&temp1,"data.temp1", "w");
//char *path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin";
pipe = _popen("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot.exe\" -persistent", "w");
//Opens an interface that one can use to send commands as if they were typing into the
//    gnuplot command line.  "The -persistent" keeps the plot open even after your
//    C program terminates.
//


int i;
for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
{
    printf("%lf %lf %lf \n", xvals[i], x1vals[i], yvals[i]); //Write the data to a temporary file
}

for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
{
    fprintf(temp, "%lf %lf \n", xvals[i], yvals[i]); //Write the data to a temporary file
    //fprintf(temp1, "%lf %lf \n", xvals[i], x1vals[i]); //Write the data to a temporary file
}

fclose(temp);

for (i = 0; i < NUM_COMMANDS; i++)
{
    fprintf(pipe, "%s \n", commandsForGnuplot[i]); //Send commands to gnuplot one by one.
}
fflush(pipe);
}
```

Any suggestion or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `_popen()` with the full path to the executable. And the path with space characters should be quoted.

```
pipe = _popen("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot.exe\" -persistent", "w");
```

On the crash at `fprintf()`, you didn't use `fopen_s()` correctly. It should be

```
FILE *temp = NULL;
fopen_s(&temp,"data.temp", "w");
if (temp == NULL) { /* open file failed */ }
```

since `fopen_s()` returns error code rather than `FILE*` like in `fopen()`.

You should also `fclose(temp);` before writing to `pipe`.

Comment: I did what you mentioned but still throwing the same error

Comment: @shreyas Sorry, it should be quoted instead of escaping space characters. Edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah that error went but program is crashing when executing the second for loop particularly fprintf statement

Comment: @shreyas Edited again for incorrect file operation.

Comment: temp is not equal to NULL  but now a window appears saying gnuplot.exe has stopped working

Comment: @shreyas `fclose(temp)` once the `fprintf(temp, ...)` loop is done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69944/discussion-between-shreyas-and-timrau).

Comment: @shreyas You `fclose(temp)` too early. It should be put after `for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++) { fprintf(temp, ...); }` and before `for (i = 0; i < NUM_COMMANDS; i++) { fprintf(pipe, ...); }`